# How to create a path-finder for a map like this?

Tags: libgdx, path-finding

I'm not sure if this is considered grid-based, because as you can see there is also a line. And that line is also a non-walkable point, I have no idea how do I create a path-finder with a non-grid-based. Currently I am using [pacman-astar](https://github.com/yichen0831/Pacman_libGdx/tree/master/core/src/com/ychstudio/ai/astar) grid-based pathfinder, but it won;t fit to my game because I am using a line to block a characters path.

**In the image below is the map with lines.**

[image]

**In the image below is the graph, white is walkable, black is not.**

[image]

**In the image below is the actual path-finding, as you can see in the red circle still passing through because I am using gridbased.**

[image]

Comment: I infer from your diagram that a diagonal is passable when one (both?) of the orthogonal connections are clear - Just add this as a check on top of the check that the diagonal grid point is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is that your pathfinding algorithm also just checks if it can move diagonally but it doesn't keep in mind that it's unable to pass diagonal if both the neighbouring blocks are walls.

For example: If you move diagonally right up, it will not check the block above and the block to the right.

Add a check to your algorithm and this should probably fix it.
Or you can just disable checking diagonal spaces.